# Spring3 to Spring4 migration, No qualifying bean of type DtoMapper found for dependency

Tags: java, spring, migration, javabeans, spring-4

I am migrating a working project from Spring3 to Spring4, I only changed the `pom.xml` and now (on deploy) the application cannot find any beans of my mappers at runtime. Weird thing is, all my integration and unit tests still work. (and I test my mappers there)

I have checked multiple possible combinations of `@Component("languagesDtoMapper")` and `@Qualifier("languagesDtoMapper")`. 
I have tried to declare the bean in my spring configuration

```
<bean id="languagesDtoMapper" class="com.project.mapper.LanguagesDtoMapper"/>
```

But whatever I do, I keep getting the following error message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.project.infrastructure.dtomapper.DtoMapper] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=languagesDtoMapper)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
```

**Structure of the project:**

in the controller :

```
 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("languagesDtoMapper")
 private DtoMapper<Languages, LanguagesTableDto> partnerLanguageDtoMapper;
```

Classes:

```
@Component("languagesDtoMapper")
public class LanguagesDtoMapper extends AbstractDtoMapper<Languages, LanguagesDto> {

public abstract class AbstractDtoMapper<Source, Target> implements DtoMapper<Source, Target> {

public interface DtoMapper<Source, Target> {

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.project"/>
```

**Any ideas are welcome**

Comment: Please use multiline code blocks to properly format your code.

Comment: Are you using an XML configuration or a Java/Annotation configuration for the component scan? Can you please also attach it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue after a 3 day search!

Spring 3 will autowire beans on the ClassName, 
Spring 4 does this on the full.package.name.ClassName.

In the controller I was calling

```java
 import a.b.c.Languages;
 import a.b.c.LanguagesTableDto;

 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("languagesDtoMapper")
 private DtoMapper<Languages, LanguagesTableDto> partnerLanguageDtoMapper;
```

and in my mapper was this :

```java
 import x.y.z.Languages;
 import x.y.z.LanguagesTableDto;

 @Component("languagesDtoMapper")
 public class LanguagesDtoMapper extends AbstractDtoMapper<Languages, LanguagesDto> {
```

The `a.b.c.Languages` was an interface, and unfortnuately the implementation, `x.y.z.Languages` is called the same. Making it very hard to find the issue.